# S3 Boto 403 Forbidden Unless Access Given to "Any Authenticated AWS User"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using Python and Boto to upload images to S3.  I can get it to work if I add a grantee of "Any Authenticated AWS User" and give this grantee permission to upload/delete.  However, my impression from the documentation and several different posts on this site is that this would allow literally any authenticated AWS user, not just those authenticated to my account, to access the bucket, which I do not want.  However, I am unable to upload files (403) if I only give upload/delete permission to the owner of the account, even though I authenticate like this:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

im = Image.open(BytesIO(urllib.urlopen(self.url).read()))
filename = self.url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
extension = self.url.split('.')[-1]
out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
im.save(out_im2, im.format)
key = bucket.new_key(filename + "." + extension)
key.set_contents_from_string(out_im2.getvalue(), headers={
    "Content-Type": extension_contenttype_mapping[extension], 
})
key.set_acl('public-read')
self.file = bucket_url + filename + "." + extension
```

What am I doing wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at least, if not the one that I was looking for.  I created a user specific to this bucket and added that user to a group with AmazonS3FullAccess permissions, which I also had to create.  Then I modified my boto requests so that they use this user instead of the owner of the account, and I added this bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::media.example.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::media.example.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This worked for me, although I don't know if the bucket policy was part of the solution or not, and I still don't know why it did not work when I was trying as the owner user.  This is, however, the more proper and secure way to do things anyway.